# How to pass any TLS or SSL security?

Tags: groovy

So I have some problems with my code, I'm trying to connect to a website that require username and password. After I try to connect it gives me an error that's saying: *javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake*

This is the code:

```
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .useTLS()
            .build()

    String[] aux = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1"]

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory f = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslContext,
            aux,
            null,
            BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)


    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(f)
            .build()

    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
    builder.setScheme("https").setHost("link")
    URI uri = builder.build()
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri)

    client.execute(httpget)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
    sslcontextnew String[] { "TLSv1","TLSv1.1" }, 
    null, 
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(csi_url);

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(
    serviceXMLRequest,
    ContentType.create("text/xml", "UTF-8"));

post.setEntity(entity);             

response = httpclient.execute(post);
```